# What levels of logging are available for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I have a Rails app running on Heroku, it runs fine. I had it running with debug level logging, but now I switched back to INFO. What other levels of debugging are available? And when running for production, what level of logging should I use?

Answer (score 16):

On Heroku you can set your log level by using the LOG_LEVEL environment variable

```
$ heroku config:set LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
```

Valid values include DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL. Alternatively you can set this value in your environment config:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

If both are set LOG_LEVEL will take precedence. You'll most likely want INFO in production.

[See the rails-stdout-logging gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging)

Comment: There is also the "unknown" level.  Check here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Answer (score 1):

Logging on Heroku is just a stream of text lines.  So you can log anything you want.  You can also filter through that stream, use add-ons for enhanced search, and get a syslog drain of your logs.

Comment: Hm, maybe my question wasn't really clear. Using `heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` you can change the logging level. I was woundering what I could use instead of "DEBUG" or "INFO".

Comment: This depends on the logging framework you are using.  What language and logging library are you using?